# Bring thumbnails to front / shuffle on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect of shuffling through a set of thumbnails when the user mouses over them, bringing the selected thumbnail to the front, like this
[Ben Mendelewicz / Comics](http://www.benmendelewicz.com/?section=comics)

As far as I can see, this site is using xGallery which is a plug-in for Joomla. I am not using Joomla, and I'm looking to replicate this effect using css/js/jQ.

Could anybody please point me in the direction or give me some advice on how to do this?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0):

The Gallery is basically raising the `z-index` of a node on `mouseover` and resetting it on `mouseout`.

But maybe you want to check out a CSS solution:

```css
/* layout */
.stack { position: relative; }
.stack .item {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* and the effect */
.stack .item {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: z-index 86400s; /*24 hours*/
}

.stack:hover .item { z-index: auto; }
.stack .item:hover {
  z-index: 2;
  transition: z-index 0ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="stack">
  <div class="item" style="background: red;    top:   0px; left:  0px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background: green;  top:  50px; left: 20px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background: blue;   top: 100px; left: 40px;"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background: yellow; top: 150px; left: 60px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty much perfect for my purposes. Thank you for taking the time to answer!